# How to create a web site using Flash like "intel museum of me"?

Tags: facebook, flash

I am new to Flash technology.

Does anyone who can show me or let me know what kind of flash API or libraries are used for making this Flash video which imports facebook content?

The website link is here:  http://www.intel.com/museumofme/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn how to connect flash with Facebook than you probably should start from [Adobe Flash and Facebook](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html) tutorials. There, apart from configuring Adobe ActionScript 3 SDK for Facebook Platform, you can found some basic code samples on how to log in to the Facebook, how to get current user, and other things.

Comment: thanks, i will go check it out.